# Remove square brackets and single quotes regex not working

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have the following string

> [custID] = 'A99999999'

I am trying the following to remove the square brackets and the single quotes

```
Regex.Replace(sql, "/[\[\]']+/g", " ")
```

but that's not working. I keep getting the same results

Note: sql is a variable holding the string above.

I want the result to be

> custID = A99999999

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\[` doesn't do what you think it does. Nor is `Regex` the same as in Perl. Try this instead:

```
Regex.Replace(sql, @"[\[\]']+", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? `['\\/]`

That should match any single character that is a slash or single quote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Regex.Replace(sql, @"[\[\]']", " ")`; the @ introduces a string where you need no escapes, and `Regex.Replace` replaces all matches, so no need for the `g` flag - your regex syntax isn't supported here, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Regex.Replace(sql, "[][']", "")
```

If you're wondering how does that work, `]` right after `[` isn't treated as closing, but as literal character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string split and join like below:

```
        string sql = "[custID] = 'A99999999'";
        var correctedString = string.Join("",sql.Split(new char[] {'[', ']', '\''}));
        Console.Write(correctedString);
```

If you want to use regex use `[\[\]']` to replace those.